# Python: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, format

I'm using DocX module for python and Mysql, so my problem today is that I'm having a problem rised from affecting `row_cells[2].text = A`, knowing that `A` is retrieved from the database, the problem wasn't exisiting knowing that the same characters where used before I was using a query with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, and also I was using `%s` instead of `.format()`.

The raised error is `ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters`

I tried `encode()`, `encode(A,'utf-8')`, I have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  in all scripts

Any help please ?

Edit: when i set my inserting back to %s everything works normal so the problem is with the format() function? anyone has an explanation?

Comment: Have you tried _printing_ ascii(A)?

Comment: There is no such a function. However when i set back my insert on the database with %s instead of format() it works normaly. im just curios to know what happening

Comment: Ah, you're on Py2 then. Ok, print repr(A) then. Also, printing type(A) might help... I guess it is unicode, but it might be str.